# How to query in Azure cosmos db where query parameter has a single qutoe

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a query is azure cosmos db

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.productConfigId in ('Levi's')
```

since Levi's contains a single quote, the query is breaking because of the comma. I checked the azure docs and they recommend to use `\'` to escape but that only seems to work when you have no trailer letter after the comma. Anyone knows the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to successfully run the query by escaping `'` with `\'`. Here's the query I ran:

```
SELECT * FROM Root r where r.Content in ('Levi\'s Jeans')
```

[image]

Other alternative is to use `double quotes (")`. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Root r where r.Content in ("Levi's Jeans")
```

Comment: Surprisingly it worked for me. I tried the following query: `SELECT * FROM Root r where r.Content in ('Levi\'s Jeans', 'Flying Machine Jeans')` and was able to get the results properly. Please see the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp7Y3.png.

Comment: Thanks. both option worked. However with the first option the issue is if i'm executing this query via code is resolves `\'` it to a single quote and then it throws an error. however with double quotes this doesn't happens.

Comment: I am using Node SDK to execute the query. What SDK you're using?

Comment: i'm using kotlin as backend to execute the query.

Comment: Sorry, not know much about Kotlin. You may want to edit your question and include your code and change tags to include `Kotlin` tag. Someone with experience there might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks. changing to double quotes worked for me anyways.